# Unable to auto refresh content

Tags: javascript, html, function

I tried setinterval and settimeout to callback validate() function,but I don't know why it just won't work. Now I try another type of calling method and still not working. Any fix?

Below is the code:

```
   function validate(){
    var code = document.getElementById("BScode").value ;
    var msg = "<p>ERROR : Please select the option. </p>";
    var error = document.getElementById("valError");
    error.innerHTML = ""; //clear error-span
    document.getElementById("divResult").innerHTML = ""; //clear resutl-div
  **  document.getElementById("map_title").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.display  = "none"; **

    if( code == "" || code == "none" || code == null ){
        error.innerHTML = msg;
    }else{
    //get result
        getETA();
        auto_refresh_countdown(seconds);
    }
  }

  /* The whole stupid function to call back refresh validate() which failed :)*/
  function auto_refresh_countdown(seconds) {
            var time = seconds;
            var myTimer = setInterval(function() {

                time--;

                if(time === 0){

                    clearInterval(myTimer);

                    validate();

                    auto_refresh_countdown(seconds);
                }
            }, 1000);
        } 

function getETA() {
    var seconds = 5;
    var id = document.getElementById("BScode").value;
    var url = "http://www.cybertowers.net/jsonp/?a=eta.aspx?bid=";
    loadData(url, getETACallback);//real
}
```

Comment: This line `uto_refresh_countdown(seconds)` wouldn't be a typo, would it...?

Comment: `uto` is not `auto`

Comment: Also, protip: if you press Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome/FF or F12 in Edge, you can open the developer tools, and on the Console tab you can see any errors your scripts are throwing. This can usually clue you in to what's wrong.

Comment: Oops,`uto` was typo in here,edited.

Comment: @MátéSafranka nope,I hope any error logs was in there but it was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line, you've got a function `getETACallback` that is not defined.
I just tried to run `auto_refresh_countdown`, it works. `validate` is only called if `seconds` is different from `1` though.
Plus you have a typo: `uto_refresh_countdown` --> `auto_refresh_countdown`

Comment: If including the `getETACallback()` it would be a very long post, and it didn't have much impact so I've cutted it (assume it was a working auto time showing function). And also, I've tried manually executing both `validate()` and `auto_refresh_countdown()` and it *does* update the data but still won't auto update at all.

Comment: It is definitely working. Check this screenshot out: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5323445/40577558-326495e6-60f7-11e8-9dcd-d32efe5612ca.png

Comment: Oh. I found that problem. I didn't define the seconds in function. Instead, I use `var seconds=5;` in the `getETA()`.